# Help with Unusual Mean Correlation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, specific-reference, correlation-functions, ising-model, ferromagnetism

I've been working on a variation of the Ising Model that tries to account for quantum fluctuations in the lattice. After doing a some calculations I calculated the mean correlation $<\sigma_i \sigma_j>$ and found this

[image]

The solid blue line is the mean correlation calculated with the Onsager Solution. The Blue Dots represent the mean correlation calculated with a variation of the Ising Model. The variation of the ising model gives a two-valued function. I'm pretty sure that one of the values minimizes the free energy but it is a difficult calculation to do.

**Have anyone seen this kind of plot before?** I would be really interested to find papers with this kind of behaviour in the mean correlation or the mean magnetization of a ferromagnetic material.

Also, if anyone knows how to deal with this kind of solutions I would be glad to listen. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of variation?

Comment: Do you expect the physics in this variation to be the same as that of the Ising model?

Comment: @valerio it has magnons and ising variables. The plot was the result of performing a mean field aproximation over the magnons to see an effective theory for the ising variables.

Comment: @ZachMcDargh I expected the correlation to decrease faster than the Onsager one but not to do that weird turn. I know that when performing a mean field aproximation you might find many autoconsistent solutions like $m=\pm 1$ and $m=0$ but I didn't expect a second solution like the one in the graphic.

I just want to know if similar plots have appeared in mean field calculations, in order to know what to do. :)